# DBAnnotations - Duplicate Annotaion

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, annotations

As a part of my course project we have been asked to annotate our code.

For the following code

```
import java.lang.annotations.*;
@Target({ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DBAnnotation {
 String variable () default "";
 String table () default "";
 String column () default "";
 boolean isSource () default false; 
}


public static void addFileToDB(String fileName, String fileLocation, int offerID){
    @DBAnnotation (variable = "fileName",  table = "files", column = "FileName", isSource = true)
    @DBAnnotation (variable = "fileLocation",  table = "files", column = "fileLocation", isSource = true)




    String SQLFileSelect = "SELECT FileName FROM files WHERE OfferID = ? AND FileLocation = ?;";
.
.
.
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Duplicate annotation @File.DBAnnotation. Repeated annotations are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
```

But if I change it to ...

```
public @interface DBAnnotation {
     String[] variable () default "";
     String table () default "";
     String[] column () default "";
     boolean[] isSource () default false; 
    }
.
.
.
@DBAnnotation (
            variable = {"fileName","fileLocation"},  
            table = "files", 
            column = {"FileName","fileLocation"}, 
            isSource = true)
```

then it does not give any error.

My concern here is, for the variable fileLocation, would te DBAnnotation be considered as 
variable = "fileLocation", table = "files", column = "fileLocation",isSource = true

or will it be considered as
variable = "fileLocation", table = "", column = "fileLocation",isSource =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it like this:

```
variable = {"fileName","fileLocation"},  
            table = "files", 
            column = {"FileName","fileLocation"}, 
            isSource = true
```

then *variable* and *column* is going to be both values, since you defined them as an Array of String.

Important thing here is that what you do with a custom annotation is only up to you (what you do with it at runtime), so :

```
  getAnnotation(DBAnnotation.class).variable(); // will return the String array with both values.
```

Comment: So for example, if I write table as .. table = {"files", "books"} ,
how could I make sure that "fileName" is associated with the table "books" and "fileLocation" is associated with the table "files" ?

Comment: @Xion you could do it through code, get the first String array and second and associate them as you wish. The second option is through complex annotations, read more here : https://blogs.oracle.com/toddfast/entry/creating_nested_complex_java_annotations